# unresolved external symbol just cropped up. Constructor trouble

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am getting these three related (I think) errors.
Any help would be appreciated. This is part of a larger project but I made most of this code a long time ago for a different project and it worked out ok. I Have started dicking around with the InsertAsFirst but haven't gotten anywhere.

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Node::Node(double,class Node *)" (??0Node@@QAE@NPAV0@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall List::insertAsFirst(double)" (?insertAsFirst@List@@QAEXN@Z)

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Node::Node(double)" (??0Node@@QAE@N@Z) referenced in function "private: static class Node * __cdecl List::clone(class Node *)" (?clone@List@@CAPAVNode@@PAV2@@Z)

Error   3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved external

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using std::ostream;


        List::List()
    : _first(nullptr)
{
}


           List::List(const List & other)
    : _first(clone(other._first))
{
}


List::~List()
{
    while (!empty())
    {
        removeFirst();
    }
}


const List & List::operator=(const List & other)
{
    // check for list = list
    if (&other != this)
    {
        // clear the current contents of this List
        this -> ~List();
        // and get a copy of other
        _first = clone(other._first);
    }

    return *this;
}


bool List::empty() const
{
    return _first == nullptr;
}


void List::insertAsFirst(double x)
{
    if (empty())
        _first = new Node(x,nullptr);
    else{
        Node * ptr = new Node(x,nullptr);
        ptr->_next = _first;
        _first = ptr;
    }
}






double List::removeFirst(){

    double item = _first->_entry;
    _first = _first->_next;
    return item;
}

double List::removeLast() {

    //returns zero if the list is empty
    double toReturn = 0;

    if (!empty()){
        Node * ptr = _first;

        //this is used for a list with 1 number
        if (ptr->_next == nullptr){
            toReturn = ptr->_entry;
            ptr = nullptr;
            return toReturn;
            //std::cout << "im heree in if statemen" << std::endl;
        }

        //used for a list with exactly 2 numbers
        if (ptr->_next->_next == nullptr){
            //  std::cout << " i made it in  the special if statment" << std::endl;
            toReturn = ptr->_next->_entry;
            ptr->_next = nullptr;

            return toReturn;
        }

        //used for a list with  more than 2 numbers
        //  std::cout << "before while loop" << std::endl;
        while (ptr->_next->_next != nullptr){
            //  std::cout << "while loop" << std::endl;
            ptr = ptr->_next;
            //std::cout << "while loop past next ptr" << std::endl;
        }
        toReturn = ptr->_next->_entry;
        ptr->_next = nullptr;
    }
    return toReturn;
}



double List::size(){
    double count = 0;
    if (_first == nullptr)
        return 0;

    else if(_first != nullptr){

        count = 1;
        Node * ptr = _first->_next;
        while (ptr != nullptr){
            count++;
            ptr = ptr->_next;
        }
        return count;
    }
    return count;
}

double List::sum(){

    double thesum = 0;
    if (!empty()){

        thesum = _first->_entry;
        Node * ptr = _first->_next;
        while (ptr != nullptr){

            thesum += ptr->_entry;
            ptr = ptr->_next;
        }
    }
    return thesum;
}


void List::insertAsLast(double x){

    if (empty()){
        insertAsFirst(x);
    }
    else{

        Node * ptr = _first;
        while (ptr->_next != nullptr){
            ptr = ptr->_next;
        }
        ptr->_next = new Node(x, nullptr);
    }
}

     double List::returnFirst(){
    return _first->_entry;
}



      void List::print(ostream & outfile) const
     {
               outfile << "[ ";
         if (!empty())
    {
        // The first entry is printed separately because no comma
        // is needed.
        outfile << _first->_entry;
        Node * ptr = _first->_next;
        while (ptr != nullptr)
        {
            outfile << ", " << ptr->_entry;
            ptr = ptr->_next;
        }
    }
    outfile << " ]";
}


     // Iterative version of clone.
     // This version walks down the linked structure making a
     //   new Node for each double in the structure.
     Node * List::clone(Node * ptr)
{
        if (ptr == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    Node * first = new Node(ptr->_entry);
    Node * last = first;
    ptr = ptr->_next;
    while (ptr != nullptr)
    {
        last->_next = new Node(ptr->_entry);
        last = last->_next;
        ptr = ptr->_next;
    }
    return first;
}


//// Recursive version of clone.
//// This version handles two cases, a linked structure with
////   no Nodes, and a linked structure with one or more
////   Nodes.
//Node * List::clone( Node * ptr )
//{
//   if( ptr == NULL )
//   {
//      return NULL;
//   }
//   return new Node( ptr->_entry, clone( ptr->_next ) );
//}


     ostream & operator<<(ostream & outfile, const List & list)
{
    list.print(outfile);
    return outfile;
}









     #ifndef _NODE_H_
#define _NODE_H_

#include <iostream>


class Node
{
public:
    double _entry;
    Node * _next;

public:
    // Constructors

    // post: this Node contains entry and a NULL pointer
    explicit Node(double entry);

    // post: this Node contains entry and next
    Node(double entry, Node * next);

    // Destructor

    ~Node();

     private:
    // Inaccessible standard functions
    Node();
    Node(const Node &);
    const Node & operator=(const Node &);
    Node(Node &&);
    const Node & operator=(Node &&);
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared a constructor but never provided a definition for that constructor.

```
Node::Node(double entry);
```

This line is trying to invoke that constructor

```
last->_next = new Node(ptr->_entry);
```

Comment: ahh okay, I will work on that

Comment: I am confused: that constructor doesn't seem any different from the other one.

Comment: LOLOL thank you  i forgot a file. Thats why i was so confused